# Break loop on successful try

Tags: python

I realize this is a low level question so apologies in advance. I've been starting at a script for too long and I'm not in python that often.

I would like to sanity check my loop below. On a successful try it should exit the loop with break. If unsuccessful try after the loop has finished it should print the message at the end. Is that expected given:

```
for n in range(0, 5):
    try:
        return connect.service.reports().batchGet(
            body = load_request
        ).execute()
    except HttpError as error:
        if error.resp.reason in ['userRateLimitExceeded', 'quotaExceeded', 'internalServerError', 'backendError']:
            time.sleep((2 ** n) + random.random())
        elif 'The service is currently unavailable' in str(error):
            time.sleep((2 ** n) + random.random())
    break
print("There has been an error, the request never succeeded.")
```

Comment: So you are looking for a CodeReview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to reach the `break` is if an exception is raised; without an exception, your function immediately returns. Just remove the `break` statement altogether. The only way to reach the final `print` call is if the loop exits naturally, without an exception ever being raised or caught.

Comment: Thanks. If I do that though, will the loop not continue iterating as opposed to moving on to the next part of the script?

Comment: No, because the `return` statement causes the function to immediately exit, without completing the loop.

Comment: To clarify, if try succeeds, I would like to exit the loop and return `connect.service.reports().batchGet(
                body = load_request
            ).execute()`

Comment: Yes, that's what `return` does.